# Emacs ERC sort channels by user count

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using ERC in Emacs as an IRC client. When I run the `/list` command, is there any way to sort the output buffer by user count (e.g. second column)?

Comment: could you screenshot how the buffer looks, including the menu/tool bar?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the source code](https://github.com/pymander/erc/blob/master/erc-list.el#L106) you should be able to click on the column and sort the list of channels that way.

Disclaimer: I haven't used /list or ERC for over a year.

Comment: Looks like it's double click